# My Huion tablet's pen doesn't seem to be working well

Tags: windows-7, graphics-tablet

So basically after around 20 days of having the tablet the pen suddenly did a lot of things that prevented me from using it.

It would draw when it was hovering, always right click(in all applications and desktop), always use the selection tool in paint tool sai despite wanting to use the brush tool.

I've tried everything I could think of and find and it still has this problem, if anyone has any idea as to why this is happening I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: It hel;ps if your specific: "I've tried everything I could think of ." Does that mean changed the battery? Rebooted?? Reinstalled drivers???

Comment: After only 20 days — try taking it back to the place where you bought it and ask them to either repair it or replace it.

Comment: one thing you can try is to disable the side-buttons on the pen via device setup program (must be there installed with drivers). Just to see if it is a pen issue. And then try to contact the manufacturer/seller.